# TypeError : timer._repeat is not a function?

Tags: node.js, timer

Having some the same question on stackoverflow such as [timer._repeat is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856593/timer-repeat-is-not-a-function) and [Run set Interval again for every interval ID in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559319/run-set-interval-again-for-every-interval-id-in-array) but I can't resolve my problem so I want to question for my special solution.

I'm using setInterval function to repeat query from database with each 30s then display on view for real-time anlytics application. When `exports.index` called I will implement select from table by `getUserRegisterPerday`function with `req` and `res` agrument referenced from `request` and `response`, the result will put on `rows` agrument from callback function to render to view.

```
var $fromTime,
    $toTime;

function getDateTime() {

    var dt = dateTime.create();
    $toTime = dt.format('Y-m-d');
    console.log($toTime);

    dt.offsetInDays(1); // + 1 day

    $fromTime = dt.format('Y-m-d');
    console.log($fromTime);

};

function repeatQueryRegister(req, res) {

    getDateTime();

    var model = new reportModel();
    // select from table on database 
    model.getUserRegisterPerday($fromTime, $toTime, function (rows) {
        res.render('index', {title: 'index', data: rows});
    });
};

exports.index = function (req, res) {

    var nInterval = setInterval(repeatQueryRegister(req, res), 30000);

};
```

But it throw an error ( view still display success)

> timers.js:275
>       timer._repeat();
>
> TypeError: timer._repeat is not a function
>       at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:275:11)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

How to fix that?

Comment: This error seems unrelated to your code. The error is occurring in `timers.js` which has nothing to do with the built in `setInterval()` command.

Comment: @Soviut: What is exactly timers.js used for?

Comment: Are you calling `clearInteval(nInterval)` at any point?

Comment: @Soviut: No, I don't. Will ``clearInteval(nInterval)`` destroy repeat it's implement?

Comment: Then this error is unrelated to your code. Check the stack trace to see what's calling `timer._repeat()`

Comment: weird !! I just only implement this ``index`` function. It displayed data on view and 30 seconds later then throw this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116419/discussion-between-soviut-and-ntlzz93).

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is dead, but in case someone else comes by:

Try changing

```
var nInterval = setInterval(repeatQueryRegister(req, res), 30000);
```

to

```
var nInterval = setInterval(function() {
    repeatQueryRegister(req, res)
}, 30000);
```

That way you're passing a function pointer and not an already processed return value.

Comment: it turned out that setInterval accepts only functions without inputs, thanks @6656342